# ”Warning: Function components cannot be given refs.“ error while using custom component in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a `HeaderIcon` component that looks like this:

```
function HeaderIcon({ inactiveIcon, activeIcon }) {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div onClick={() => setIsActive(!isActive)}>
      {isActive ? activeIcon : inactiveIcon}
    </div>
  );
}

export default HeaderIcon;
```

When I run my code I got these errors:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.
```

And I checked my console and saw this:

```
Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?
```

This is where I used my `HeaderIcon`:

```
function Header() {
  return (
    <IconContext.Provider value={{ size: "30", color: "#374957" }}>
      <header className="flex items-center justify-around py-1.5 px-3 bg-white">
        <div className="flex items-center space-x-2 w-full max-w-xs">
          <h1 className="text-4xl">Zipp</h1>
        </div>

        <div className="py-2.5 px-4 flex items-center">
          <InputGroup>
            <InputLeftElement
              pointerEvents="none"
              children={<SearchIcon color="grey" />}
            />
            <Input
              type="text"
              bg="whitesmoke"
              w={"full"}
              focusBorderColor="none"
              border={"none"}
              placeholder="Search"
            />
          </InputGroup>
        </div>

        {/* right */}
        <div className="flex items-center space-x-6">
          <div className="headerIcons active:opacity-80">
            <Link href="/">
              <HeaderIcon
                inactiveIcon={<AiOutlineHome />}
                activeIcon={<AiFillHome />}
              />
            </Link>
          </div>

          <div className="headerIcons">
            <HeaderIcon
              inactiveIcon={<MdOutlineAddBox />}
              activeIcon={<MdAddBox />}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="headerIcons -rotate-12">
            <HeaderIcon
              inactiveIcon={<AiOutlineNotification />}
              activeIcon={<AiFillNotification />}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="cursor-pointer">
            <Avatar w={7} h={7} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
    </IconContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are adding a Functional Component inside Next.js's `Link` tag, there are some changes to be made. Here is an overview of what the say in the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#if-the-child-is-a-functional-component):

> If the child of `Link` is a functional component, in addition to using `passHref`, you must wrap the component in `React.forwardRef`.

Which means, first you should add `passHref` prop to `Link` when using `HeaderIcon`, this way:

```
<Link href="/" passHref>
   <HeaderIcon
      inactiveIcon={<AiOutlineHome />}
      activeIcon={<AiFillHome />}  
    />
</Link>
```

Then change `HeaderIcon` to the following code. Notice I'm using `useRouter` from Next.js to handle active and inactive state.

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
const HeaderIcon = ({ onClick, href, inactiveIcon, activeIcon }, ref) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  return (
    <a href={href} onClick={onClick} ref={ref}>
      <div>{router.pathname ? activeIcon : inactiveIcon}</div>
    </a>
  );
};
export default React.forwardRef(HeaderIcon);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function HeaderIcon(props) {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);

  const { inactiveIcon, activeIcon } = props;

  return (
    <div onClick={() => setIsActive(!isActive)}>
      {isActive ? activeIcon : inactiveIcon}
    </div>
  );
}

export default HeaderIcon;
```

I hope this will be helpful for you. Thanks